# PHP Curl not storing json_encoded echoed data

Tags: php, curl

Does anyone no if it is possible to store echoed results from a Curl script.

Example of script been submitted to:

```
\\some code to generate images using imagick and the post variables

$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$result = json_encode($array);
echo $result;
```

Example of Curl:

```
$id = 1;
$champ = array("product" => "1","id"=> $id,"occasion"=> $o,"field1" => "1991","field2" => "test","field3" =>"test1","field4" => "test2","field5" =>"test3","field6" =>"test4","field7" =>"test5","field8" =>"test6","test7");
foreach($champ as $key => $data){
    $field_string .= $key."=".$data."&";
}
rtrim($field_string, "&");

$url = "http://www.test.com/website/script.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($champ));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $field_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$array = json_decode($result);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($array);
```

If i var_dump($result) i get a bool(true) so i know that the script has executed correctly and the output shows on screen however i don't seem to be able to store the information into a variable to process.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are not actually posting a POST variable named "submit", are you?

Comment: no this is just an example i will update the code above bad example

Comment: Please note i can view the output which is the json_encoded array but i am unable to store the data

Comment: `curl_exec()` should never return `true` when `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is turned on. Maybe the problem is there. Where can you view the output, in the 2nd PHP script or when you point your browser to the first one?

Comment: I can view the output in the curl file which it has got from the script creating the images. I have tried without the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER but it made no difference and sorry i meant it returned true when was set to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [curl_exec documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) says:

```
curl_exec() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set,
it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.
```

In your case you turn `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` off.
Turn it on by

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

and check the $result again.

Note: building a request using foreach loop and rtrim() you may damage it if your data contains `&` character.

Just use [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) with your `$champ` :

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($champ));
```

Comment: thank you i think it was a combination of set to false and the foreach loop instead of http_build_query. Thank you very much!