# Use curl to post to another PHP script

Tags: php, post, curl

I have two PHP scripts. One posts a message "Hello" while the other receives it. Currently, the second PHP script receives a _POST['message'] but the contents of that message is empty!

Script One:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
 'message' => 'Hello'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($result) {
echo("Successful post");
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Script Two:

```
if($_POST['message']) {
  echo("received post message");
  echo ("message:" . $POST['message']);
```

Currently script Two prints "received post messagemessage:"

I'm completely flummoxed - from looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589160/using-curl-to-submit-retrieve-a-forms-results), it seems my syntax is correct....

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618160/php-curl-not-storing-json-encoded-echoed-data I had a similar issue

Comment: Hard to spot typo: `$POST` should be `$_POST`.  This means you need to turn on `display_errors` and crank up `error_reporting` because you would have seen a `Notice: undefined variable $POST`.  Always in development, do `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Also, when debugging I recommend working backward. If you didn't get what you expected from `$_POST['message']`, broaden it a little to the full array and check `print_r($_POST);` there, you would have seen your expected value.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is related to a minor typographical error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script two has wrong syntax, it must be `$_POST`.

```
if($_POST['message']) {
  echo("received post message");
  echo ("message:" . $_POST['message']);
```

Comment: @AllieCat, Welcome . Don't be ^_^